# Check if time is inbetween timerange in Android

Tags: java, android, time, range

I am trying to check if the current time is in the range of a specified range. I made a method to check this, but it doesn't work. I'm not sure why not and how to get it to work.

```
private Calendar fromTime;
private Calendar toTime;
private Calendar currentTime;

public boolean checkTime(String time) {
    try {
        String[] times = time.split("-");
        String[] from = times[0].split(":");
        String[] until = times[1].split(":");

        fromTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.valueOf(from[0]));
        fromTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(from[1]));

        toTime= Calendar.getInstance();
        toTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.valueOf(until[0]));
        toTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(until[1]));

        currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();       
        currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.MINUTE);
        if(currentTime.after(fromTime) && currentTime.before(toTime)){
            return true;
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         return false;
     }
    return false;
}
```

I am trying to test it like this:

```
if(checkTime("06:00-19:00")){
    inRange = true;
}
```

The NPE is gone, but it's still not calculating if the time is in the range of `fromTime` to `toTime`. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: do you define fromTime and toTime, anywhere?

Comment: `currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.MINUTE);` and `currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);` do not do what you expect. Better read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: Yes, sorry! Check my edit!

Comment: Why do you use *fields* instead of *local variables*? BTW: The NPE occurs because you never initialize `toTime` and `currentTime`.

Comment: You cant use toTime.set() You have to initialize it before. So better place toTime = Calendar.getInstance(); before calling set(), Similarly for currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();

Comment: @still_learning Thanks for the tip, I will use local variables.

Comment: @Gem Thanks, that totally slipped past. It works now! Atleast I think it works, we'll see in 2 minutes when it is past 19:00 :)

Comment: Never mind dear we all learn from each other !! This is what we called social learning !!

Comment: just got on that question, and it appear to be incorrectly formulated. If i understand correctly, the NPE is fixed.

Comment: The NPE is fixed, will edit that, thanks. However it's still returning true, while the time is not in the range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize variables and change the return type of your method to boolean.

```
private Calendar fromTime;
private Calendar toTime;
private Calendar currentTime;

public boolean checkTime(String time) {
try {
    String[] times = time.split("-");
    String[] from = times[0].split(":");
    String[] until = times[1].split(":");

    fromTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(from[0]));
    fromTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(from[1]));

    toTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    toTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(until[0]));
    toTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(until[1]));

    currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.MINUTE);
    if(currentTime.after(fromTime) && currentTime.before(toTime)){
        return true;
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to change that before posting it here!

Comment: and i recommed the use of Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY instead of alendar.HOUR

Comment: Thanks for your input, will test it right now, since it still returning `true`, while it is not.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Misread your answer, sorry for my confusion :)

Comment: Guys Just dont set Current Time's hour and minute. You will be able to get correct information then.

Answer (score 2):

You have not initialized toTime and fromTime objects before using them. So better call toTime = Calendar.getInstance(); before.

```
private Calendar fromTime;
private Calendar toTime;
private Calendar currentTime;

public boolean checkTime(String time) {
try {
    String[] times = time.split("-");
    String[] from = times[0].split(":");
    String[] until = times[1].split(":");

    fromTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    fromTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.valueOf(from[0]));
    fromTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(from[1]));

    toTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    toTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.valueOf(until[0]));
    toTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(until[1]));

    currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.MINUTE);
    if(currentTime.after(fromTime) && currentTime.before(toTime)){
        return true;
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I don't get any NPE's anymore. So thats one obstacle down. It's still returning that the time `06:00-19:00` is in range, while it is not. I've tried setting the timezone like this: `currentTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1"));`

Answer (score 1):

this

```
    currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Doesn't do what you would like it to do. What it does is set the field HOUR to the value of Calendar.HOUR, which is an arbitrary constant.

You don't need those 2 lines as `getInstance` returns a Calendar at the current time.

Comment: Thanks for your input, removed those lines and no more NPE, however the comparision isn't working yet. Any idea why not?

Comment: yes. you are using the HOUR field when you should use the HOUR_OF_DAY field.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();



    //cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    String date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    String dateStart = date+" "+"11:30:00";

    String date2 = sdf.format(cal2.getTime());
    String dateStop =  date2+" "+"23:00:00";

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentTime =  format.format(calendar.getTime());



    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    Date d3 = null;


    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);

    d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
        d3 = format.parse(currentTime);
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+dateCal,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (d3.before(d2)
                && d3.after(d1) ){}else{} } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put **currentTime** outside of **setTime** and remove ***if-statement*** from **setTime**.
If you need put ***if-statement*** outside of **setTime**.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private boolean checkBedTime(String time) {
    // Time Pattern Like : "06:00-19:00"
    String[] times = time.split("-");
    String[] from = times[0].split(":");
    String[] until = times[1].split(":");

    int fromHour = Integer.parseInt(from[0]);
    int fromMinute = Integer.parseInt(from[1]);

    int toHour = Integer.parseInt(until[0]);
    int toMinute = Integer.parseInt(until[1]);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int currentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    int convertedFromMinute = (fromHour * 60) + fromMinute;
    int convertedToMinute = (toHour * 60) + toMinute;
    int convertedCurrentMinute = (currentHour * 60) + currentMinute;


    if (convertedFromMinute == convertedToMinute) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sleep Time & Wake Up Time can't be same", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;

    } else if (convertedToMinute < convertedFromMinute) {
        convertedToMinute = convertedToMinute + (24 * 60);
    }
    Log.v("Time", "FromMinute --> " + convertedFromMinute);
    Log.v("Time", "ToMinute --> " + convertedToMinute);
    Log.v("Time", "CurrentMinute -- > " + convertedCurrentMinute);
    if (convertedCurrentMinute >= convertedFromMinute && convertedCurrentMinute <= convertedToMinute) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.